# How to change the style of a button

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have plugin MemberPress. When I add my class, the button "Login" does not change. How to do it right, so everything works?

Original code

```
<div class="submit">
     <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit"  class="button-primary mepr-share-button " value="<?php _ex('Log In', 'ui', 'memberpress'); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_html($redirect_to); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mepr_process_login_form" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mepr_is_login_page" value="<?php echo ($is_login_page)?'true':'false'; ?>" />
 </div>
```

My code

```
<div class="btn-white">
 <div class="submit">
     <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit"  class="button-primary mepr-share-button " value="<?php _ex('Log In', 'ui', 'memberpress'); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_html($redirect_to); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mepr_process_login_form" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mepr_is_login_page" value="<?php echo ($is_login_page)?'true':'false'; ?>" />
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: please also show the minimal css that should style the button so as you expect

Comment: Are you using custom css or your own styles?

Comment: I think you should try <button type="submit"></button> instead of <input type="submit">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You HTML code should be something like below,

```
<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary mepr-share-button btn-white" value="<?php _ex('Log In', 'ui', 'memberpress'); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_html($redirect_to); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mepr_process_login_form" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="mepr_is_login_page" value="<?php echo ($is_login_page)?'true':'false'; ?>" />
 </div>
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/KoKEeN?editors=1100)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even the codepen didn't work? Can you specify the browser in which you are viewing the page? Also it would be great if you can provide the rendered HTML code. Finally, please make sure your CSS file is correctly accessed in your page.

Comment: Please tell me your e-mail, I will send you the full code.

Comment: Please join here - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/166534/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-49190832-how-to-change-style-buttom-49191669?tab=general

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to speak in the room.  Write me please - alexbalatsan@gmail.com

Comment: You can comment out the lines 8,9 and 10 `<script type="text/javascript">
          window.location.href="<?php echo urldecode($redirect_to); ?>";
        </script>` and see your codepen working fine.

Comment: https://www.theactiontakersclub.com/login/  I did not write this code. This is a plugin. I need to change the button.

Comment: I see the button styles are getting applied when the styles I had given are used correctly. Please ping me over skype - gibinealias

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add that class to the button itself. So if this is your login button, you want to add the `btn-white` class:

```
<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit"  class="button-primary mepr-share-button btn-white" value="<?php _ex('Log In', 'ui', 'memberpress'); ?>" />
```

Comment: make sure your css selector is either more specific or it's last in the cascading order because you're competing with the `btn-primary` styles. So using a selector like `input.btn-white` or `.btn-white.btn-primary` so it'll override the `btn-primary` styles.